# What happened to OmniXML?

Tags: delphi, omnixml

There seems to be a great deal of enthusiasm about OmniXML, but omnixml.com is offline and the Google Code project is empty. What happened to this library and where can I find the code (since it's open source)?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The [OmniXML Google Code project](https://code.google.com/p/omnixml/) does have source available if you click on the "Source" link, but you'll need a Subversion client to get the source.

I made a local Mercurial repository with the releases I could easily collect and a few modifications.  I'll archive the entire repo and throw it online for anyone to download...

It's available at http://www.traumazone.com/OmniXML.7z

Changes from the official source:

- Support for xml:space attribute as created by [Ondřej Pokorný](http://www.kluug.at/xlsx-ods-delphi.php)
- Shuffled source around and created Delphi 2007 and XE packages
- Updated 3rd party units with latest versions from upstream sources (e.g. `jedi.inc`, [`GpDelphiUnits`](https://code.google.com/p/gpdelphiunits/))
- Add optional useBoolStrs parameter to SetNodeTextBool

The Mercurial history is available in the archive, so you can always roll back to a different release (what few I bothered to collect).

Comment: @ChrisThornton: You and me both!

Comment: Since omnixml.com now also refers to the Google Project, which does indeed contain up to date code, your answer will be accepted.

Comment: also added a simple XPAth patch to the latest code downloadable from Googlecode